# Error when running npm test

Tags: node.js, reactjs, integration-testing

I'm new to testing in React and so I'm trying to implement some tests for an application I've already been working on.

I run npm test and I get this error:

[image]

Here's the default test in file `App.test.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
});
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use JEST + ENZYME to test React Component you can get more details https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme and https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started

Comment: Jest and enzyme is a great combination